# MySQL 5.7+, JSON_SET value in nested path

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysql-json

For a recent development project, we're using MySQL 5.7, so we can take advantages of the latest JSON-functions...

I'm building an UPDATE-query, where an nested json-object should be inserted / added into the attributes-column, of type JSON, see query below.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `table`.`name` = 'Test',
    `table`.`attributes` = JSON_SET(
         `table`.`attributes`,
         "$.test1", "Test 1",
         "$.test2.test3", "Test 3"
     )
```

When I execute this query, the attributes-field contains the data

```
{"test1": "Test 1"}
```

instead of the wanted

```
{"test1", "Test 1", "test2": {"test3", "Test 3"}}
```

Also tried to use JSON_MERGE, but when I execute it multiple times, it creates an JSON-object like

```
{"test1": ["Test 1", "Test 1", "Test 1"... etc.], "test2": {"test3": ["Test 3", "Test 3", "Test 3"... etc.]}}
```

So, JSON_SET isn't working when nodes don't exist? JSON_MERGE merges till infinity?

The keys used in the JSON-object can be defined by the user, so it's not possible to create an empty JSON-object for all possible keys. Do we really need to execute an JSON_CONTAINS / JSON_CONTAINS_PATH query before each UPDATE query to determine if we need to use JSON_SET or JSON_MERGE / JSON_APPEND?

We're looking for a way to have a query which always works, so when `"$.test4.test5.test6"` is given, it will extend the current JSON-object, adding the full path... How can this be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now, as of MySQL version 5.7.22 the easiest way is to use `JSON_MERGE_PATCH` like this:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `attributes` = 
JSON_MERGE_PATCH(`attributes`, '{"test2": {"test3": "Test 3"}, "test4": {"test5": {}}}')
```

which gives the expected result of `{"test1": "Test 1", "test2": {"test3": "Test 3"}, "test4": {"test5": {}}}` as in your example.

Comment: JSON_MERGE_PATCH will remove keys from the results, for which the key value in the second object is JSON null literal. [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-patch)

Answer (score 24):

As of MySQL version 5.7.13, assuming you desire an end result of

```
{"test1": "Test 1", "test2": {"test3": "Test 3"}}
```

In your example the `attributes` column that is being updated is set to `{"test1": "Test 1"}`

Looking at your initial `UPDATE` query, we can see `$.test2.test3` does not exist.
So it can not be set as

> JSON_SET() Inserts or updates data in a JSON document and returns the
> result. Returns NULL if any argument is NULL or path, if given, does
> not locate an object.

Meaning MySQL can add `$.test2`, but since `$.test2` is not an object, MySQL can not add on to `$.test2.test3`.

So you would need to define `$.test2` as a json object by doing the following.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM testing;
+----+---------------------+
| id | attributes          |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | {"test1": "Test 1"} |
+----+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> UPDATE testing
    -> SET attributes = JSON_SET(
    ->     attributes,
    ->     "$.test1", "Test 1",
    ->     "$.test2", JSON_OBJECT("test3", "Test 3")
    -> );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM testing;
+----+---------------------------------------------------+
| id | attributes                                        |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"test1": "Test 1", "test2": {"test3": "Test 3"}} |
+----+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So instead of relying on the MySQL dot notation, you would need to explicitly tell MySQL that the key exists as a JSON object.

This is similar to how PHP also defines non-existent object property values.

```
$a = (object) ['test1' => 'Test 1'];
$a->test2->test3 = 'Test 3';

//PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value
```

To get rid of the error, you would need to first define `$a->test2` as an object.

```
$a = (object) ['test1' => 'Test 1'];
$a->test2 = (object) ['test3' => 'Test 3'];
```

Alternatively you could test and create the objects prior to using the dot notation, to set the values. Though with larger datasets this may be undesirable.

```
mysql> UPDATE testing
    -> SET attributes = JSON_SET(
    ->     attributes, "$.test2", IFNULL(attributes->'$.test2', JSON_OBJECT())
    -> ),
    -> attributes = JSON_SET(
    ->     attributes, "$.test4", IFNULL(attributes->'$.test4', JSON_OBJECT())
    -> ),
    -> attributes = JSON_SET(
    ->     attributes, "$.test4.test5", IFNULL(attributes->'$.test4.test5', JSON_OBJECT())
    -> ),
    -> attributes = JSON_SET(
    ->     attributes, "$.test2.test3", "Test 3"
    -> );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM testing;
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | attributes                                                                |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"test1": "Test 1", "test2": {"test3": "Test 3"}, "test4": {"test5": {}}} |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Though in either case if the original data is not provided the JSON_OBJECT function call will empty out the nested object's property value(s). But as you can see from the last `JSON_SET` query, `$.test1` was not provided in the definition of `attributes`, and it remained intact, so those properties that are unmodified can be omitted from the query.

Comment: Does this not just makes dealing with JSON documents a real pain ? I mean in the case when the structure is unknown and nesting is deep. Which exactly when one would turn to JSON IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Fyrye, thanks for the awnser, appreciate it a lot! Because of the data hasn't a fixed structure and can be different for every single record, I needed a solution where I could generate a query which would automatically generate the total JSON-object in a single query.

I really like your solution using the `JSON_SET(attributes, "$.test2", IFNULL(attributes->'$.test2',JSON_OBJECT()))` method. Because I continued my search, I also figured out a solution myself using `JSON_MERGE` function.

When i'm executing an update, i'm using `JSON_MERGE` to merge an empty JSON-object onto the field in the database, for all keys with subnodes, so the're available in the JSON-field in the database and after that, using `JSON_SET` to update values. So the complete query looks like this:

```
UPDATE table SET
    -> attributes = JSON_MERGE(
    -> attributes, '{"test2": {}, "test4": {"test5": {}}}'),
    -> attributes = JSON_SET(attributes, "$.test2.test3", "Test 3");
```

After executing this query, the result will look something like this:

```
 mysql> SELECT * FROM testing;
 +----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | id | attributes                                                                |
 +----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |  1 | {"test1": "Test 1", "test2": {"test3": "Test 3"}, "test4": {"test5": {}}} |
 +----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I don't know which method is better at this time, both work for now. Will do some speed tests in the future to check how they preform when 1 update 10.000 rows!

Comment: This is real pain IMO. I have submitted a feature request
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84167. Maybe if you have minute you could support it by clicking the effects me button : ) Or comment.

Answer (score 0):

After searching everywhere like many of you I've found the best possible solution listed here: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,647956,647969#msg-647969

From the site:
he nodes and subnodes, but doesn't contains any data... 
So in above example, the object will be like:

```
{"nodes": {}}
```

When executing an update, i'm using `JSON_MERGE` to merge the empty JSON-object onto the field in the database, so all the nodes / subnodes are available in the JSON-field in te database and after that, using `JSON_SET` to update values. So the complete query looks like this:

```
UPDATE table SET attributes = JSON_MERGE(attributes, '{"nodes": {}'), attributes = JSON_SET(attributes, "$.nodes.node2", "Node 2")
```

For now, this is working. 
But it's an weird workaround. Maybe this can be reviewed in previous MySQL versions, so `JSON_SET` also creates parent-nodes when subnodes are set ?

Comment: Hi Gregor,

This post is already 2 years old. After reporting this issue / problem at MySQL (see: bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84167), the've made some changed / created new functions for JSON in MySQL. Have a look at the JSON_MERGE_PATCH (Availabline since MySQL 5.7.22), this might be a better solutions for your problem, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-patch